# Why my suggest call does not return any matches?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have `post` type which has field `title`. For now there are following titles:

```
"post title 1"
"post title 2"
"post title 3"
...
"post title 200"
```

In `post` mapping there is:

```
properties:
    ...
    title:
        type: "string"
    ...
```

I am able to search for post title however following suggest request does not return any matches:

```
{
"index-name": {
    "text": "post",
    "phrase" : {
        "field" : "title"
    }
}   
}
```

result:

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "index-name": [
        {
            "text": "post",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 4,
            "options": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I use `POST .../index-name/_suggest` endpoint
It also fails for text `"1"`, `"200"` etc

I guess I have to update mapping to let know elastic that I want to use this field for suggestions, however I can't find it anywhere in docs...

Answer (score 0):

You should use "completion" type instead of "string" for title.

And try to search for "post" text.